# If a monotonic function $F$ on [a,b] with $F'$ exist and finite value, then $F$ is absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $F$ is a monitonic function on [a,b] and $F'$ exist with finite value, then $F$ is absolutely continuous.
I want to show F' is bounded then $$\sum_{v}(F(b_v)-F(a_v))\le M(b_v-a_v)$$
But I'm not sure whether or not $F'$ is bounded.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple proof. Using monotonicity you can easily verify that $F'$ is integrable and this implies absolute continuity by a non-trivial theorem which can be found in Rudin's RCA>

Comment: The inequality you've written down just means that $F$ has bounded variation, which is (trivially) true for any bounded monotonic function. Being AC requires the proof of a stronger condition.

Comment: On the left hand of the inequality,$(a_v,b_v)$ denote the disjoint intervals,I think it is quite diffierent from the definition of variation function.